# Certification exams discussions in chat rooms

Tags: discussion, chat

I was wondering if it's possible to discuss about certification exams (Java, JSF, Oracle ...) in chat rooms? I tried to find if it's off-topic but could not find any information on this.

If not, I'm really interested in creating one, so that users may benefit from others feedback.

Comment: Well, chat rooms have different rules (basically undefined behavior).

Comment: thanks @πάνταῥεῖ for replying. But, I can't understand downvoters, I would appreciate if they left some comment, thus if my answer is so bad I can delete it I have no problem on that!

Comment: @Tarik I left one? And I don't think it's a good idea (may depend on a particular chat room).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok I didn't knew it's you :) no worries and thanks for the comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is on and off-topic for chat rooms *differs from room to room*.

Ask the room owners or regulars for their rules. Many use the room information blurb to include a link to their rules, if they have them written down. Always respect the room owner's wishes.

It's fine to start a new room for the subject if you cannot find any rooms that would have you. As long as you stick to the [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) you are free to use a room for subjects of your own choosing.

Comment: Many thanks Martijn Pieters for your answer, Thus If I create one regarding the certification I specified it's ok ?

Comment: Sounds like a perfectly fine topic to discuss!

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot! I feel like I had to start it a long time ago